# How to get required number of entries using Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

I am using [Twitter Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) to get 10 entries for a particular search term.

I issued:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%40cldmgc&rpp=10
```

But I am getting only 5 entries.

Is there anyway I can resolve this which doesn't require authentication?

Comment: I also want to include 'page' option
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%40cldmgc&rpp=10&page=2
should return next 10 entries

Answer (score 0):

You problem isn't rate-limiting, instead you've run into one of the annoying limitations of the search API: it only returns results for about the last four days. For your query, there have only been five status updates in the last four days, and that's all you will be able to fetch.

If, however, your search terms yielded more than five results (like this query for the word "purple": http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=purple&rpp=10) you will find that Twitter has nicely included in your results the query you need to get the next page of results.

```html
<link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?max_id=86674031113289728&amp;page=2&amp;q=purple&amp;rpp=10" rel="next"/>
```

Just read the *href* from the `<link>` having `type="application/atom+xml"` with `rel="next"`. After your XML parser decodes the href, you'll have a URL in the form: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?max_id=86674031113289728&page=2&q=purple&rpp=10

Comment: Is there a way I can extend the day limit or can this be done using Stream API. Because I need atleast 10 tweets per page.

Comment: The default Twitter Web Client fetches more than 10 tweets for the same search term.

Comment: First, no, you can't get more than four days from the search endpoints; Twitter is limiting the results. Second, you could use the streaming API, but you would only get tweets from the point after you connected; I'd just hit the search API.

Comment: Third, what search are you performing where you are getting any results from earlier than June 27th? The Twitter website search and search.twitter.com are both returning the same 9 results, 4 of which were from the time period after you posted your question. See http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%40cldmgc, http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40cldmgc, and http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/%40cldmgc